# Numerical precision of comparison operators

Tags: c++, numerical-stability

Short question: is the behavior of comparison operators defined at max precision?
Meaning, if I have two numbers (x and y) that are identical up to precision, should I always expect the same answer when I do x < y?

I realize this might seem like a dumb question, but let me elaborate. 
I am working with `double` and I have an array of numbers like:

```
0:  62536.5477752959
1:  62536.4840613718
2:  62536.4576412381
3:  62522.8487197062
4:  62536.5473896233
5:  62536.5467941254
6:  62527.3508907998
7:  62536.5477752959
8:  62517.5900098039
9:  62536.5477752959
```

Notice that entries 0, 7 and 9 have the same value.

When I do (something like this) :

```
int low = 0, high = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  if(x[i] < x[low])
    low = i;
  if(x[i] > x[high]) 
    high = i;
 }
 cout << "low: " << low << " high: " << high << endl;
```

I sometimes get: `low: 8 high: 0`, sometimes: `low: 8 high: 7`
I would have expected always the lowest index value.

Any ideas?

[edit missing braces.]

Comment: How did you load the values into the array?

Comment: Maybe replate/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: There's no such thing like a _specified precision_ for `double` values? Are you confusing that with their text representeation?

Comment: There might be some braces missing in the code provided.

Comment: `i` is never initialized, so that could be undefined behavior and give inconsistent results.

Comment: The longer story is that this is happening in one of my optimization classes. The class has a a function pointer to an user provided cost-function that evaluates for example y = x^2. The class provides x and gets back y, which is the values of the arrays I am showing.   @rex, thanks for the braces and initializaton i, this is not actually the code I am using, just for getting the point across

Comment: @Randi: Hum. My answer still stands. Out of interest, it's better to use x * x to evaluate the square of x rather than one of the std::pow overloads.

Comment: @Bathsheba, Thank you for the answer, but I am still confused. I am outputting the values to a file using [max_digits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10). I don't understand why they would be different.  x^2 is just an example, the actual cost functions are more complicated, involving pixel differences of images. When I look at the different returned values form the cost function they are all the same (in the printed manner mentioned above)

Comment: How are you looking at those values?

Comment: `std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10) << y[i] << std::endl;`  T = double

Comment: @Randi, forgive the arrogance (?!), but my answer still stands. The problem, I conject, is elsewhere. But don't blame floating point relational operators. They are fine, trust me.I suggest you re-ask - the question in it's current form is still useful - with more specific criteria; an answer will emerge quite quickly. (Just two doubles, the recipe for constucting them, and the faulty comparison will be sufficient.) Note that your numbers are hardly *subnormal* so there's nothing funky there to consider.

Comment: You were right @Bathsheba. What I didn't mention in the post above is that the actual cost function is partially computed in CUDA, which was the root of the [numerical issues](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html). Once I took care of those, the comparison operators did what they are supposed to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, assuming IEEE754 for your floating point types. Any two `double` values `x` and `y` say are such that exactly one of `x < y`, `x == y`, or `x > y` holds, with the exception of some edge cases like +Inf, -Inf, or NaN.

Confusion starts to arise when you use decimal notation to represent floating point values; e.g. there is no such `double` as 62536.5477752959 (or any other one on your list for that matter).

The numbers that you present have been truncated by your debugger / standard outputter, they are *not* the ones being used in the actual algorithm that you present. Be assured that the same decimal number **always** produces the same `double`, there is no arbitrary choice being made here: IEEE754 mandates that the closest `double` is picked.

For further reading, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Finally, replace `int i` with `int i = 0`. Currently the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the output of the program varies. We should assume that parsing the exact same string representation of a decimal number will produce the exact same `double`, hence from your three alternatives `x == y` should hold between numbers `0` and `7`. What is making the program think that `7` is smaller _sometimes_?

Comment: @jdehesa: Oops, yes I missed that. Have amended the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba, the values are being printed with the max # of digits possible. e.g. `std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10) << y_[i] << std::endl;` where `T = double`. I assume that the same number of digits and the same values for each digit would lead as you said to the same output. But that is not what I am seeing.

Comment: I've addressed this in the question comments.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use libraries to sidestep the behaviour/limitations of built-in types:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db8bc9030f778bcd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using Float = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100;
    std::vector<Float> values = {
        Float{ "62536.5477752959" }, Float{ "62536.4840613718" }, Float{ "62536.4576412381" }, Float{ "62522.8487197062" },
        Float{ "62536.5473896233" }, Float{ "62536.5467941254" }, Float{ "62527.3508907998" }, Float{ "62536.5477752959" },
        Float{ "62517.5900098039" }, Float{ "62536.5477752959" },
    };

    auto hilo = std::minmax_element(values.begin(),values.end());

    std::cout << "low: " << *hilo.first << " high: " << *hilo.second << std::endl;

}
```

Prints

```
low: 62517.6 high: 62536.5
```

To print indexes:

```
// indexes:
std::cout << "low: " << (hilo.first-values.begin()) << " high: " << (hilo.second-values.begin()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: The goal seems to be to find the index of max and min values, not the values themselves. Also, even though using a library may help, it doesn't really answers why the original program does not work as expected in some cases.

Comment: @jdehesa see edit - I'm aware that I didn't answer that, I was helpful in addition to the standard answers and comments. It's a beat-to-death subject but solutions are sometimes required

Comment: @sehe: I have you down as being in the top 5 smartest contributors on this site. But your answer seems a little incomplete to me. Do feel free to grab the starting text from mine - I'm sure you've learnt nothing from it!

Comment: On the contrary, @Bathsheba. I consider my answer a mere appendix to yours :)

Comment: @sehe. Have an upvote all the same. To me though the humble `double` gets a bad press. It's a wonderful construct, capable of representing a Planck length, the diameter of the universe, and the distance from here to Pluto to the nearest centimetre.

Comment: @Bathsheba Cheers! It's not the range that trips people up :)

Comment: @sehe thank you for the suggestion. I would like to avoid moving way from the build-in types if possible.